# neo4j Batch Importer Issues with Automatic Indexing

Tags: neo4j

I tried to use Batch Importer to import CSV data into neo4j database.

At first I tried to import data without automatic indexing and it worked well. After that, I tried to use automatic indexing on example data nodes.csv and rels.csv:

*nodes.csv:*

```
name    age works_on
Michael 37  neo4j
Selina  14
Rana    6
Selma   4
```

*rels.csv:*

```
start   end type        since   counter:int
1     2   FATHER_OF 1998-07-10  1
1     3   FATHER_OF 2007-09-15  2
1     4   FATHER_OF 2008-05-03  3
3     4   SISTER_OF 2008-05-03  5
2     3   SISTER_OF 2007-09-15  7
```

The batch.properties file contains the following lines:

```
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=15M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=15M
batch_import.node_index.users=exact
```

When trying to run batch importer on Windows, I got the following exceptions:

*I:\Research\Temporal Analysis\neo4j>java -server -Xmx4G -jar batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar data/graph.db nodes.csv rels.csv node_index users fulltext nodes_index.csv rel_index worked exact rels_index.csv*

```
Using Existing Configuration File

Total import time: 0 seconds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Type stri
ng:users
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.importer.Type.fromString(Type.java:71)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.importer.RowData.parseTypes(RowData.java:52)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.importer.RowData.<init>(RowData.java:25)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importNodes(Importer.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:57)
```

Looking for similar issues encountered by others, I came across [this](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/issues/41).

As I downloaded a Windows-ready jar file from [this address](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/downloads), I'm wondering whether it contains any bugs or there is an error in any of .csv files or batch.properties.

If anyone managed to import auto-indexed data into neo4j database on windows machine, I would be very thankful to describe the right procedure.

Thank you!

Comment: Now I built the newest version and used the same settings and data and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to specify the csv column to be indexed, augmenting the header.
For instance, if the property to be indexed is **name**, its header should be as follows

```
name:string:chewbecca
```

Where your index is called, ie. *chewbecca*.

Second, you have to set the right name of the index in the property file.
As your configuration, you have set the following:

```
batch_import.node_index.users=exact
```

Now you have to specify *chewbecca* --- instead of *users* :

```
batch_import.node_index.chewbecca=exact
```